# JQ adds single quotes while saving in environment variables

Tags: environment-variables, jq

OK, this might be a silly question. I've got the `test.json` file:

```js
{
    "timestamp": 1234567890,
    "report": "AgeReport"
}
```

What I want to do is to extract `timestamp` and `report` values and store them in some env variables:

```sh
export $(cat test.json | jq -r '@sh "TIMESTAMP=\(.timestamp) REPORT=\(.report)"')
```

and the result is:

```sh
echo $TIMESTAMP $REPORT
1234567890 'AgeReport'
```

The problem is that those single quotes break other commands.
How can I get rid of those single quotes?

NOTE: I'm gonna leave the accepted answer as is, but see [@Inian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5291015/inian)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57043236/2194119) for a better solution.

Comment: `eval $(cat test.json | jq -r '@sh "export ..."')` ?

Comment: awesome, thanks @jhnc. would you like to make it an answer or should I do it?

Comment: `eval "$(...)"` -- without the quotes you can get all sorts of surprises; compare the two different `eval` operations in `s=$'printf \' - %s\\n\' *'; eval "$s"; eval $s`. (Or, much better, use Inian's answer and avoid using `eval` at all, suggested reading: *[BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048): Eval command and security issues*)

Comment: may I suggest that use of `cat` is entirely superfluous as `jq` will open/read the file given to it from command line: `jq -r '...' file.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the jq man-page, the `@sh` command converts its input to be

> escaped suitable for use in a command-line for a POSIX shell.

So, rather than attempting to splice the output of jq into the shell's export command which would require carefully removing some quoting, you can generate the entire commandline inside jq, and then execute it with `eval`:

```
eval "$(
    cat test.json |\
    jq -r '@sh "export TIMESTAMP=\(.timestamp) REPORT=\(.report)"'
)"
```

Comment: eval $(jq -r '@sh "export TIMESTAMP=\(.timestamp) REPORT=\(.report)"' test.json) works as well.

Comment: I tend to assume it's being used as a placeholder for a more complicated pipeline but, yes, this is a useless use of cat

Comment: Excellent.  Nice usage of @sh.  I haven't seen that referenced anywhere else and it's definitely more reliable than anything I would have managed otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Why make it convoluted with using `eval` and have a quoting mess? Rather simply emit the variables by joining them with NULL (`\u0000`) and read it back in the shell environment

```
{
  IFS= read -r -d '' TIMESTAMP 
  IFS= read -r -d '' REPORT
} < <(jq -r '(.timestamp|tostring) + "\u0000" + .report + "\u0000"' test.json)
```

This makes your parsing more robust by making the fields joined by NULL delimiter, which can't be part of your string sequence.

Comment: Hm this is too much for me :D it does seem cleaner but a bit more advanced maybe? I'll try to use it. Thanks.